# Move horizontally an <ImageView> pressing a <Button>

Tags: java, android, button, imageview

I'm developing a Space Invaders in AndroidStudio (without Libgdx, Gamemaker...) using just Java and XML and I have a problem... I hope you will help me.

First of all, here is my [**app design**.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8Tuv2.png)
 [image]

As you can see, at the bottom of the RelativeLayout you could find a spaceship and two buttons (one at left and the other button at right of the ship). The buttons are invisible. The left button has "control_izquierda" as id and the right button, "control_derecha".

When you press the left button, the spaceship moves to the right, and when you press the right button, the spaceship moves to the left (this works perfectly).

My problem It's about moving the spaceship while one of the buttons is pressed (**when I hold down the button, the spaceship should move**). I have tried different ways to try this but I can't find the correct solution.

Here is my **java code**

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    }

    public void actualizaPosicion(View v) {
        switch (v.getId()) {
            case R.id.control_derecha:
                findViewById(R.id.nave).setX(findViewById(R.id.nave).getX() - 30);
                break;
            case R.id.control_izquierda:
                findViewById(R.id.nave).setX(findViewById(R.id.nave).getX() + 30);
                break;
        }
    }

}
```

When one of the buttons is clicked, my XML calls at "actualizaPosicion" method. This method detectes if the right or left button has been clicked and then upload the spaceship position (which id is "nave"), and I want when a button is holding down, the spaceship moves, and when a button is no longer press, the spaceship stops.

I appreciate the help.

Thank you so much!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you need is an animator handling animation [Click here to view api docs](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/graphics/view-animation.html)

Once you understand the basic flow you will just have to create a xml file with different values ( in your case **translate** ). So in your button on click java code you can simply initiate this animation xml file.

**//example xml**

```
<set android:shareInterpolator="false">
    <scale
        android:interpolator="@android:anim/accelerate_decelerate_interpolator"
        android:fromXScale="1.0"
        android:toXScale="1.4"
        android:fromYScale="1.0"
        android:toYScale="0.6"
        android:pivotX="50%"
        android:pivotY="50%"
        android:fillAfter="false"
        android:duration="700" />
    <set android:interpolator="@android:anim/decelerate_interpolator">
        <scale
           android:fromXScale="1.4"
           android:toXScale="0.0"
           android:fromYScale="0.6"
           android:toYScale="0.0"
           android:pivotX="50%"
           android:pivotY="50%"
           android:startOffset="700"
           android:duration="400"
           android:fillBefore="false" />
        <rotate
           android:fromDegrees="0"
           android:toDegrees="-45"
           android:toYScale="0.0"
           android:pivotX="50%"
           android:pivotY="50%"
           android:startOffset="700"
           android:duration="400" />
    </set>
</set>
```

**//example java code for usage**

```
ImageView spaceshipImage = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.spaceshipImage);
Animation hyperspaceJumpAnimation = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(this, R.anim.hyperspace_jump);
spaceshipImage.startAnimation(hyperspaceJumpAnimation);
```

Hope this helps. Please let me know if it changes anything for you.

**EDIT**: I understand from the comment that you are looking for a more complex solution that involves creating a **game** and not just simple animation.

So I would like to share one resource with you which will definitely help you out with this and future projects as well. It is not possible to explain each and every aspect of game development here using answers.

[Click here for full detailed android space game tutorial](http://gamecodeschool.com/android/coding-a-space-invaders-game/)

Comment: Hi, Nishant. I think this solution doesn't be usefull in this case. All I need is this: When I hold down the left button, the spaceship have to move to the right side while I keep it down, when I don't longer press the button, the ship will be stopped. I can't use an animation, I need to move the ImageView to another position. If I first hold down the left button and the spaceship moves 30 dp and then I want to hold down the right button to move the spaceship to left, you way isn't usefull.

Comment: Hey, I understand your requirement. I have updated the answer accordingly. Am sure this will solve all your current and future issues with this game. **It's not just animation that you need. It's full fledged game development that's why I can't give all code examples in answers**. Please do accept my answer if the edited link turns out to be the tutorial you were looking for.